# Linq To SQL : Insert data 

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a database, I create a dbml file and drop the tables it. I can get data like this :

```
MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext ();

var query =
       (from lg in db.Languages
        select lg).ToList<Languages>();
```

No problem, I get the data.

I'd like insert, I tried this :

```
 db.Languages.Add(new Language() { ..... });
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

The "Add" does not exist in the method list .....

What is the solution ?

Thanks,

PS : it's a project .NET 3.5 with VS2010

Comment: why .NET 3.5 with VS2010? why not .net 4.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
db.Languages.Add(new Language() { ..... });
```

I think you want this:

```
db.Languages.InsertOnSubmit(new Language() { ..... });
```

Comment: When this change has been introduced ? On ScottGu blog he is not using your syntax .... but your syntax works :)

Comment: I don't think `Add` was ever present in a production release of LINQ-to-SQL.  If it were, MS would probably tag it `[Obsolete]` instead of removing it outright, or they would risk breaking existing code.  Perhaps the method was present in an early alpha or beta, and was changed before the first release.  (Just guessing here.)